# json string into key value NSArray iPhone

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray

I get back a json of structure like

{ ResultCount =7; ResultLimit=30; ResultList=({ AlbumId=111;ArtistId=203},{AlbumId=112;ArtistId=203}); Status=0}

The ResultList is an array. How can I get the AlbumId and ArtistId in an NSArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi happy_iphone_developer,

ResultList is not a Array and it's NSDictionary.

```
 NSString *urlDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:RecievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init]; 

NSError *error = nil;

 NSArray *resultArray = [parser objectWithString:urlDataString error:&error];

NSString *extractString = [[resultArray valueForKey:@"ResultList"] valueForKey:@"AlbumId"];
```

Whatever you want to extract, use this way to extract the particular data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

are you wanting to make good json ? then,

```
{ ResultCount:7, ResultLimit:30, ResultList:[{ AlbumId:111,ArtistId:203},{AlbumId:112,ArtistId:203}]}
```

or you want to parse  in iPhone then

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework

is good framework

Answer (score 0):

Just use a JSON framework like [this](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

The ResultList is not a NSArray, it's a NSDictionnary.